# Which elements combine to form new elements in Magicka?

Tags: magicka

So I've been playing Magicka for a few days now (and haven't experienced most of the bugs that everyone else is), and I'm curious to know what element combinations people have found so far, e.g. Water+Fire=Steam, Water+Cold=Ice, etc.

Note: I'm not looking for your super-awesome-high-damage-spell-combo (though there are some pretty cool ones, that seems a bit subjective), just elements that combine together on the spellbar rather than remaining separate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those you mentioned:

Water + Fire = Steam
Water + Cold = Ice

are the only sub-elements in the game right now.

Comment: Bit depressing; I was hoping I just missed some. Maybe they'll add more later on, after the choppiness goes away and multiplayer is playable.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a late answer but..

- Water + Fire = Steam (spray)
- Water + Cold = Ice (projectile)
- Water + Arcane/Life(can't remember which) = Poison (spray)

not sure if there are more but asfar as i remember these are sub-elements

Comment: Have a downvote -- poison doesn't appear that way, or water would be unable to get to the target by beam spells.